# Div widths not resizing evenly in mobile browser

Tags: css, mobile, html, viewport

I'm building a non-responsive website with a header a footer that spans the full width of the browser window. Inside of the DIV's with a width of 100%, I nested divs with a width of 1000px that holds the header, navigation and footer contents.

My problem is that when viewing the site on a mobile device, the navigation and footer are being scaled downed to a size that is slightly smaller than the header and main area of the site.

What's strange is that the navigation and footer are affected while their is no issue with the header (that is built with the same approach).

How can I get everything to scale proportionally? The width of the entire site and all of the main divs is 1000px so why are they coming out in different sizes on mobile devices?

Here is the site's URL: http://www.test-site.co.nf

Here is a code sample:

HTML:

```
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<div id="header-content">
<div id="logo">
<a href="index.html"><img src="img/ama-party-rentals-logo.png" height="98" width="500"/></a>
</div>
<div id="social-icons">
<a href="" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="img/icons/facebook.png" height="40" width="40"/></a>
<a href="" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="img/icons/googleplus.png" height="40" width="40"/></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="nav-bar">
<div id="nav">
<ul id="ul-nav">
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="">Company</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past &nbsp; Events</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact &nbsp; Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">Francais</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
   background-color:#84B13F;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
     border-bottom-color:#648830;
  border-bottom-width:5px;




}

#header-content
{
  width:1000px;
  height:150px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  background-image:url('img/top-banner.png');


}

#nav-bar
{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#84B13F;
  border-bottom-style:solid;
  border-bottom-color:#648830;
  border-bottom-width:5px;

}

#nav
{
      clear:both;
      margin:auto;
      height:50px;
      width:1000px;
      text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: could you add your codes to jsFiddle, so we could play with it and see if can find solution?

Comment: Hi, I actually figured out the answer last night I was just unable to post the answer until today because I am a new user. Thanks for responding though!

Comment: then put your answer and mark that, so other people could get benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issue in your site.

1) in css cass boxes-div have width 1000 and margin-left: 20px. So the actual 1000px + 20px total 1020px which is out of your layout.

2) your nav size is 1020px but your header is 1000px so when you are at mobile or a small device (max screen 999px) showing only 1000px which is little bit small then the full site.

Change the width of the header to 1020px that should solve the issue.

To be more specific

```
   #header-content{
       padding: 0px 10px;
       /**your present css**/
    }
```

Just update your #header-content add the padding and your site is fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the boxes-div where the width was spilling outside of the parent div, unfortunately this did not solve my problem.

Comment: Changing the header and the other divs to a width of 1020px helped to make the site scale to a full width size on mobile browsers but it did not solve my problem with the navigation and footer not scaling proportionally. Setting a min-width for the div wrapping the whole site did rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out:

My problem was that I had a container DIV that is wrapping the whole site. In that container I had height set to 100% but no width defined. I set the min-width to 1020px and voila; no more broken, cutoff divs. my header and footer divs that are set to 100% width scale down but the scaling stops at 1020px in width for the entire site so all of my content displays the way I intended it to on mobiles and desktop. Thanks to all who responded!

Comment: I made this solution your problem few days ago. It would be a honest work to select my answer as solution.

Comment: You told me to change the header with which did not solve my problem. However, it did indirectly lead me down the road towards finding the solution that eventually remedied my issue. I should have given you credit for that and I apologize that I didn't in my last comment. Thanks for taking the time.